# XML and XML Schema creation in Intellij

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Eclipse has functionality to create XML file and XML Schema. Did Intellij have this functionality. I tried multiple options but could find it.
[image]

In Intellij, i can see xml actions but not way to create xml schema
[image]
I want to create xml schema from scartch.

Comment: You may use "Tools | XML Actions | Generate XSD Schema from XML File" action when XML file is opened.

Comment: I looking for a functionality that create schema file from scratch. I am not sure if IntelliJ have this functionality like eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I see those options in IntelliJ (Tools/XML Actions) but they are greyed out, I assume because some plug-in is needed. I think if you're doing a serious amount of XML development, you should get a specialist IDE like Oxygen for XML work rather than relying on IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, thank you for suggestion. You are right I should prefer other IDE for xml schema development.